# How to bind a WPF control to multiple sources but only display the most most recently updated source

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a TextBox that I want to bind to two sources (source A and source B).
I want to display source A when that gets updated and source B when the user provides input.
I don't want to display the data from both sources at the same time.

I tried using a priority binding, but that doesn't appear to work the way I want it to.

```
<TextBox>

<TextBox.Text>
    <PriorityBinding>
        <Binding ElementName="Features_ComboBox" Path="SelectedItem.Address" Mode="OneWay" />
        <Binding Path="UserAddress" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay"/>
    </PriorityBinding>
</TextBox.Text>

<TextBox>
```

Ideally the textbox will be updated when the "Features_ComboBox" selected item changes, but if the user writes in the textbox it will update the "UserAddress" property (hence the mode settings).

What happens instead is that the "Features_ComboBox" updates the textbox but the UserAddress never gets updated.

I also tried using MultiBinding, but i was less successful with that.
Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I am afraid that you have to use a behaviour for this. A behaviour with your 2 binding sources and the behaviour just directly assign their values to your Textbox.

Comment: Yes, it seems I will need to use a behavior - I'm not familiar with how behaviors work, my next step is to figure that out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.prioritybinding):

> The binding engine starts with the first binding in the list and verifies whether that binding returns a value successfully; if it does, the value from that binding is used. If the first binding does not return a value successfully, the binding engine examines the second binding to determine whether it returns a value successfully; if it does, the value from the second binding becomes the active value. This verification process continues to the end of the list of bindings. If none of the bindings returns a value successfully, the binding uses the FallbackValue.
> The binding engine continues to listen for changes on all bindings. **If at any point one of the bindings that has a higher priority returns a value successfully, the value for that binding becomes the active value and replaces the current value.**

Note that the selection of the `Binding` to use is based *solely* on updates to the source of the binding. If the source doesn't change, the active binding isn't changed. Furthermore, in your own example, even if the source property `UserAddress` had changed, that binding would still not become active because you placed the `Binding` object at a lower priority than the `ComboBox` binding.

The `PriorityBinding` object will always prefer the higher-priority, i.e. earlier-ordered, binding in its list. As long as that binding is producing a value, no other binding will be selected.

The `PriorityBinding` object simply does not have the behavior you want. It's for a completely different kind of scenario.

I recommend that you solve the problem in the view model. For example, you can bind the `ComboBox` and the `TextBox` to separate view model properties. Then in the view model, if and when the `ComboBox` selection is modified, you can explicitly copy that data to the `TextBox`'s *source* property, which will then update the `TextBox.Text` property.